# How to print the byte array as the following

Tags: c#

I have a byte array and I would like to print the value every two bytes, and convert every two bytes to integer.

```
00 0f 00 13
```

will be printed as:

```
15 , 19
```

Comment: this doesn't seem much more vague than a lot of the questions I've seen on here, but it looked like he has a byte stream of little endian shorts and he wants to extract or unpack them into 16 bit values.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

short x = (array[0] << 8 | array[1]);

This or some permutation for C# will convert the first two bytes to a short. You can then add 2 to each of the indices until you increment through.

```
for( int i = 0; i < array.size(); i+=2 )
{
  print( (short)((array[i] << 8) | (array[i+1])));
}
```

Apologies for incompleteness, I'm doing this on my Mac :).

Comment: (+1 for writing C# code on an Apple)

Comment: in PC, need to use )((array[i+1] << 8) | (array[i]));

Comment: BTW, how to write C# under Mac?

Comment: There are Mono interpreters for *nix to do this. I use it in Eclipse. I still prefer Microsoft Visual Studio, but doesn't yet exist natively on Macs :).